# Placing R command in PATH Environment Variable (Windows)

Tags: python, r, path

I am attempting to install the rpy2 module, but experienced this error:

```
Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.
```

I tried editing the PATH in Environment Variables, adding

```
...;C:\Program Files\R"
```

but that didn't work.

What edits need to be made to the PATH variable in Environment Variables so that the install of rpy2 will be able to locate the install of R?